# Shutterbug NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-shutterbug

I am executing some selenium tests and wanted to add *Shutterbug* to my project for screenshots. I Added a mvn dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.assertthat</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-shutterbug</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and started to code. It works as expected local, but when I wanted to run it on Jenkins, it gave me *NoClassDefFound* exception:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   SomeTest.test:38 » NoClassDefFound com/assertthat/selenium_shutterbug/util...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

I have deleted all the code related to this library and just have now only the dependency in pom.xml. It fails even now. I found out that failure occures when I run it on Jenkins or when I run it local but in *headless* mode. How can I get it work?

Comment: IT fails locally when running headlessly? But runs otherwise?

Comment: @DMart yes. And it also fails in Jenkins